# How to Delete all folders inside a folder except one in windows batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I tried to delete a files and folder inside a folder except one ,but so far I didn't get a perfect answer for it?

Can any one help on this above?

My folder structure seems like this:

I have ABC Folder under E:\ Inside that folder I have 4 files named A.txt,B.txt,C.txt & D.txt and I have 3 Folders in that they are AB , BC & CD ...I want to remove all files and folders in ABC folder except CD folder inside ABC folder..

Can any one please help on the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this - it should work.

```
pushd "d:\abc\cd" && rd /s /q "d:\abc" 2>nul
```

Answer (score 1):

pushd "d:\abc\cd" && rd /s /q "d:\abc" 2>nul will delete all the files inside the folder cd.

Comment: What will be the command if I want to keep 2 folders and its contents ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you know exactly yout directory tree, you can just remove all element you don't need:

```
del e:\abc\ab\*.*
rmdir e:\abc\ab
del e:\abc\bc\*.*
rmdir e:\abc\bc
```

More general solution:

```
for /D %%d in (e:\abc\*) do if "%%d" neq "CD" rmdir "%%d"
```

Comment: For this to work it would need to read:
`for /D %%d in (e:\abc\*) do if "%%d" neq "e:\abc\CD" rmdir "%%d"`